# CAShapeLayer doesn't show up

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, cashapelayer, swift4.2

I am trying to add a `CAShapeLayer` to a view. But when I add the `customView` to ViewCOntroller's View, the shapeLayer doesn't show up. Capturing hierarchy shows that the layer doesn't even get inserted to the View. Here is the code:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
...

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        let diameter = min(self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: diameter/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: true)
        let sLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        sLayer.frame = bounds
        sLayer.path = path.cgPath
        sLayer.fillMode = .backwards
        sLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor//bubbleColor?.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(sLayer)
    }
```

And in ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let node = Node(frame: CGRect(origin: self.view.center, size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)))
        self.view.addSubview(node)
...
}
```

I really do not understand what is happening. Please help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you setting `layerClass`, but then adding a `CAShapeLayer`. So, you've got two completely different `CAShapeLayer` instances. Is that your intent? Why are you changing the base `layerClass`?

Comment: I was trying without it. And then got a reference here with it. I just added it and mistakenly copied over here. 

Comment: OK. No worries. You can do rendition of this with `layerClass` if you want, but then we don’t add sublayer. It’s one or the other.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks for solving the problem on both perspective. `Constraints` were playing a vital role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

1. adding your sublayer in `init` (so it's added once and only once);
2. configure its `frame` and `path` in `layoutSubviews` (so if it's resized, whether by constraints or some other mechanism, the layer will update accordingly);
3. when adding a subview/sublayer whose dimensions is based upon the size of the current view, reference the view’s `bounds` (the coordinate system within the current view), not the `frame` nor `center` (both of which are in the coordinate system of the superview); and
4. either use `addSublayer` approach or `layerClass` approach, but not both.

Thus, adding `CAShapeLayer` as sublayer:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var bubbleColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleColor.cgColor } }

    private lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let sLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        sLayer.fillColor = bubbleColor.cgColor
        return sLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        updatePath()
    }
}

// MARK: - Utility methods

private extension CircleView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let diameter = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: diameter / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

---

Or, if you want to use `layerClass` approach:

```
@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var bubbleColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleColor.cgColor } }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }

    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return layer as! CAShapeLayer}

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

// MARK: - Utility methods

private extension CircleView {
    func configure() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleColor.cgColor
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let diameter = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: diameter / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }
}
```